# What's the "choose an application to associate with" window in MacOS?

Tags: macos, ms-office, parallels-desktop

I run Outlook 2016 for Windows inside a Parallels Desktop (latest version, currently 12.2.1) Windows 10 VM. Occasionally when WiFi is slow, Outlook for Windows shows a dialog box along the lines of "requesting info from server. please wait".

When Outlook for Windows would show these warning boxes, sometimes a Mac window (not a Parallels coherence window but a real Mac window with MacOS chrome) would pop up inviting me to associate these dialog boxes with an application, and it showed me a list of applications.

Once I did what that window asked and chose Outlook. Big mistake!  I accidentally chose Mac Outlook, not Windows Outlook. Now every time Outlook for Windows has a network problem, Mac Outlook (which I otherwise never use) is launched and starts chewing up my CPU and disk while processing the last few weeks of mail.

Does this mysterious "choose your application to associate this dialog with" window on the Mac sound familiar?  Is this a Paralells-specific window, or is it shown by Mac OS unrelated to Parallels?

In any case, I want to undo my choice made above. How do prevent Mac Outlook from being launched whenever Windows Outlook shows a network problem dialog?

I wish I'd been smarter and captured a screenshot of that mysterious window when it popped up, which would make it possible to solve this problem via Google.  But because I don't know what that mystery window was titled, I'm stumped for how to undo what I did.